# Como actualizo una celda sin hacer doble fila Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Buen dia tengo una tabla en la cual lleno los siguientes campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los primeros dos los llena automaticamente por que los busco con un modal que esta en la la lupa, los otros 3 tengo que llenarlos... al momento de darle click en el +
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Automaticamente me añade la fila, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que cuando quiera añadir el mismo registro con el mismo ID unicamente me actualice la celda de CANTIDAD en la parte de abajo. Lo que no quiero es que haga doble fila.

```
 //--Grabar Producto--//
    function ProductoGuardar() {
        var Producto = {
            ProductoFila: $("#txtIdProducto").val(),
            ProductoCodigo: $("#txtCodigo").val(),
            ProductoNombre: $("#txtDescripcion").val(),
            ProductoCostoActual: $("#txtCostoActual").val(),
            ProductoCantidad: $("#txtCantidad").val(),
            Descuento: $("#txtDescuento").val(),
            ProductoTotal: $("#txtCostoActual").val() * $("#txtCantidad").val() - $("#txtDescuento").val(),
        }

        //Buscar si existe producto
        var productoNuevo = 0;
        tabladata
            .column(1)
            .data()
            .each(function (value, index) {
                if (value == $("#txtCodigo").val()) {
                    productoNuevo = 1;
                    toastr["warning"]("Producto ya existe")
                }
            });
        //--- Validaciones de valores en campos
        if ($("#txtCodigo").val() == "") {
            productoNuevo = 1;
            toastr["error"]("Debe indicar un producto")
        } else {
            if ($("#txtCantidad").val() == 0) {
                productoNuevo = 1;
                toastr["error"]("Debe indicar una cantidad")
            }
        }
        //--- Funcion GUARDAR
        if (productoNuevo == 0)  {
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ objeto: Producto }),            //el "objeto" debe estar en el controler, envia objeto definido arriba con todos los campos, el STRINGIFY: es para convertirlo a texto
                    success: function (data) {
                        tabladata.row.add(Producto).draw(false); //Esta agregando una filA mas con la informacion solicitada de Usuario                     
                        toastr["success"]("Producto agregado")
                    ///Guardo el siguiente valor en la caja te texto txtIdProducto
                    var Fila = parseInt($("#txtIdProducto").val()) + 1;
                    $("#txtIdProducto").val(Fila);
                    ///Limpio variables para un nuevo producto
                    $("#txtCodigo").val("");
                    $("#txtDescripcion").val("");
                    $("#txtCostoActual").val("0.000000");
                    $("#txtDescuento").val("0.000000");
                    $("#txtCantidad").val("0");
                    $("#txtCodigo").focus();
            //},
```

> Esta funcion la llamo al boton + que miran en la img

```
"columns": [
            { "data": "ProductoFila" },
            { "data": "ProductoCodigo" },
            { "data": "ProductoNombre" },
            { "data": "ProductoCostoActual"
                , render: function (data) {
                    return ' <input type="text" id="tableCostoActual" style="font-size: 12px;" class="form-control text-center floatNumberField" value="' + parseFloat(data).toFixed(6) + '">';
            }
            },
            { "data": "ProductoCantidad"
                , render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return '<input type="text" id="tableCantidad" style="font-size: 12px;"  class=" form-control full-width text-lg-center" value="' + parseFloat(data).toFixed(0) + '" >';
                }
            },
            { "data": "Descuento"
                , render: function (data, type, row) {
                    return ' <input type="text" id="tableDescuento" style="font-size: 12px;" class="form-control text-center floatNumberField" value="' + parseFloat(data).toFixed(6) + '">';
                }
            },
            { "data": "ProductoTotal" },
            {
                //pestaña no agregada en DB
                "defaultContent": '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ms-2 btn-eliminar"> <i class="fas fa-trash"></i> </button>', //ms-2: modificar las distancia de separacion del icono
                "orderable": false,
                "searchable": false, // ESTO SIGNFICA QUE AL MOMENTO DE BUSCAR UN CONTACTO, NO MUESTRE ESTE COLUMNA CON LOS DOS BOTONES
                "width": "20px" //modificar ancho de la columna
            }
        ],
```

> El codigo de arriba son los inputs que estan dentro de la tabla

Comment: Yo tuve un problema similar, lo único que hice fue ver mi proceso almacenado en mi base de datos y modifiqué la query, agregando un `GROUP BY`, así ya no me listaba doble.

Comment: @Isanchezo fijate que yo aun esa tabla no la e conectado a la Base de datos, lo que quisiera es unicamente hacer el cambio en datatable. Me podrias ayudar disculpa...